# Conditional Formatting, adding whole number and percentage?

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, percentage

Hello everyone looking for some help with the following.

I have a Excel spreadsheet setup for inventory purposes. 
There are multiple tabs and a Master tab. 
All tabs are using  `vlookups` to populate from the Master.

The Master in turn uses vlookups to copy and add the data entered by the user on the other multiple tabs.
Users enter data in columns O, Q & S I have set conditional formatting so that if the cell to the right of it has a % sign then it is to be formatted as a %. If the cell to the right does not have a % sign present then it is simply formatted as a number.

Everything transfers over to the Master sheet without any problems, but on the master sheet there is a total column and when it totals it counts the percentages as a whole number.

For instance O=1, Q=1, S=3% ,U(=O+Q+S)=5
For whatever reason column U doesnt recognize that S is a % which I assume is due to the conditional formatting that column S has.

Any thoughts, thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure that the percentage values are stored as percentage values?  If you click on the cell it should say 0.03 in the formula displayer, not 3. By the way, what is the point of adding apples and oranges (whole numbers and percentages)?

Comment: Good questions. (1) If they enter 30 for 30% it shows 30% in the cell but when looking at the formula display it shows as 3000%. (2) Ideally I would prefer it to just be entered as decimals but the sheet is used by about 100 different people and they of course do not like change and want to keep it as a %.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work and so far seems to give the desired results...

in column U I have entered =IF((SEARCH("%",T24)), S24*0.01+Q24+O24, S24*1+Q24+O24)

The only problem I can see first off is I would need to make sure that column T is the only one that contains the %'s, otherwise I will need to find a way for it to check each column.

Comment: Do you store the percentage values as text?